# Ethereum transaction "fail" because of "revert". "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] "

Tags: transactions, ethereum, revert

I have a ERC20 Token on the mainnet of Ethereum.
the normal method "transfer" is working finde.
I have built another function "performFeelessTransaction" to pay the transactions for everyone.

So this function is working fine on Ropsten and Kovan, not on mainnet. I have no clue why.

This is a failed transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc0ea0f2fe90f128fff25737539cebe98070dfb3e5d9e9513756cbb4b462cd0b5

My Contract is:
EIP20.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

import "./EIP20Interface.sol";
import "./Feeless.sol";

contract EIP20H is EIP20Interface, Feeless {

```
uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
/*
NOTE:
The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
*/
string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX
address owner;                        // Adress of the Owner


constructor(
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string memory _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string memory _tokenSymbol
) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
    name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;
    owner = msg.sender;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

modifier onlyOwner() { 
    require (msg.sender == owner);
    _; 
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function transferFeeless(address _to, uint256 _value) public feeless returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msgSender] >= _value);
    balances[msgSender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msgSender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
    require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
    if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    }
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}

function addTotalSupply (uint256 _value) public onlyOwner {
    totalSupply += _value;
    balances[msg.sender] += _value;
}
```

}

Feeless.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

import "./ECRecovery.sol";

contract Feeless {

```
address internal msgSender;
mapping(address => uint256) public nonces;

modifier feeless {
    if (msgSender == address(0)) {
        msgSender = msg.sender;
        _;
        msgSender = address(0);
    } else {
        _;
    }
}


function performFeelessTransaction(address sender, address target, bytes memory data, uint256 nonce, bytes memory sig) public payable {
    require(address(this) == target);
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(target, data, nonce))));
    msgSender = ECRecovery.recover(hash, sig);
    require(msgSender == sender);
    require(nonces[msgSender]++ == nonce);

    target.call.value(msg.value)(data);
    msgSender = address(0);
}

function performFeelessTransaction2(address sender, address target, bytes memory data, uint256 nonce, bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public payable {
    require(address(this) == target, "Error 801");
   // bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
   // bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(target, data, nonce))));
    // msgSender = ECRecovery.recover(hash, sig);
    msgSender = ECRecovery.verify(hash, v,  r, s);
    require(msgSender == sender, "Error 802");
    require(nonces[msgSender]++ == nonce, "Error 803");

    target.call.value(msg.value)(data);
    msgSender = address(0);
}

function getNonce()public view returns(uint256){
    return nonces[msgSender];
}
```

}

How can i find out the reason for the failure?
Best regards Ruwen